# Re using super class methods by avoiding overriding of super class methods java in a specific scenario

Tags: java, overriding

I have two classes 
 ClassA :
     with 4 member variables of different data types and 3 methods(m1(),m2() and m3())

eg :

```
class ClassA
       {
           String a;
           String b;
           Double c;
           UserDefinedTypeA d;
         public m1(){
            //All the 4 variables are used here.
           }
         public m2(){
             //All the variables are used here.
           }
         public m3(){
            //All the variables are used here.
           }
```

ClassB : 
     with 4 member  variables and 3 methods(m1(),m2() and m3()). 
Three of these member variables of same type as ClassA and only the fourth variable type is different.

eg :

```
class ClassB
       {
           String a;
           String b;
           Double c;
           UserDefinedTypeB d;
         public m1(){
            //All the 4 variables are used here.
           }
         public m2(){
             //All the variables are used here.
           }
         public m3(){
            //All the variables are used here.
           }
```

Now i would like avoid to overriding of m1,m2 and m3 in sub class because of the type 4th member variable is different. 
As a solution i am planning to create another member variable in super class with the type : UserDefinedTypeB and initialize this variable from subclass constructor . Have a check inside the all the methods for whether UserDefinedTypeB is null or not . If it is not null the i will execute subclass specific logic otherwise will continue with super class logic which supports UserDefinedTypeB.

But felt this will reduce the performance . Any suggestion on coming up with better approach.

Comment: What's the subclass and what's the superclass?  It's really not clear from your question.  It seems to me that the right solution probably involves generics - so you might have a generic superclass `SuperClass<T>` where `ClassA extends SuperClass<UserDefineTypeA>` and `ClassB extends SuperClass<UserDefinedTypeB>` where all the common functionality lives.  But I can't say for sure because I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Better Approach is to introduce in super class SuperClass and move 3 common variables and logic for m1() , m2() and m3().

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    String a;
    String b;
    Double c;

    public void m1(){
        //All the 4 variables are used here.
        m1logic();
    }

    public void  m2(){
        //All the variables are used here.
        m2logic();
    }

    public void  m3(){
        //All the variables are used here.
        m3logic();
    }

    public abstract void  m1logic();

    public abstract void  m2logic();

    public abstract void  m3logic();
}

public class ClassA extends SuperClass {

    UserDefinedTypeA d;

    public void m1logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }

    public void m2logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }

    public void m3logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }           
}

public class ClassB extends SuperClass {

    UserDefinedTypeB d;

    public void m1logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }

    public void m2logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }

    public void m3logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Generics:

```
public abstract class SuperClass<T> {
    String a;
    String b;
    Double c;
    T d;

    public void m1(){
        //All the 4 variables are used here.
        m1logic();
    }

    public void  m2(){
        //All the variables are used here.
        m2logic();
    }

    public void  m3(){
        //All the variables are used here.
        m3logic();
    }

    public abstract void  m1logic();
    public abstract void  m2logic();
    public abstract void  m3logic();
}

public class ClassA extends SuperClass<UserDefinedTypeA> {
    public void m1logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }

    public void m2logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }

    public void m3logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeA logic
    }           
}

public class ClassB extends SuperClass<UserDefinedTypeB> {
    public void m1logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }

    public void m2logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }

    public void m3logic(){
        // UserDefinedTypeB logic
    }           
}
```

I would also use `double` rather than `Double`, unless you have a really good reason otherwise.